# DateTime with frames for a Video system

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a `string` coming from a video system as `2015-05-23 23:59:45:02` The last octet `02` is the frames for the video. I want to convert this to a `DateTime`. The string has following format: `dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss:ff`. I tried the following:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(sTime, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It gives me the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How to get this correctly ?

Comment: It's  unclear why you expect that `"dd/MM/yyyy"` should work for `"dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss:ff"`, especially because your string contains `-` as delimiter and not `/`.

Comment: The method name is *Parse**Exact***. What you used is definitely not the exact pattern in the string. Parse the string first, then extract the date-only part

Comment: @Tim: I want to convert to a `DateTime`.

Comment: BTW dates have no format. They are binary values. There's no way that you can convert the frame number to milliseconds either. When you parse that string, the result will be a full datetime value with milliseconds equal to that value. *If you know the frame rate* and if the last pair of *characters*, not octets, is a frame inside a second, you could try multiplying milliseconds by the frame duration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I want to keep the frame duration as it is.

Comment: What frame duration? You said this is the frame number. Frame duration is eg 20ms for a 50fps video. If you try to treat *frames* as if they were milliseconds, you'll just end up with invalid data. Your sting for exampel speicifies `20 ms`. Milliseconds aren't *precise*, so they *can* change

Comment: @user726720 if you want to translate a *Video Timecode*, you should use a custom class, *not* DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the exact date to `ParseExact` (notice the name)

```
string input = "2015-05-23 23:59:45:02";

var dt= DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ff");
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. :), Just changed the `hh` in `ToString` to `HH` to get the 24hrs.